# How do I hide the code of my theme?

Tags: theming

Is it possible to hide the code of the theme that I have created for my client? In other words, when I open the page with firebug I dont want to see the HTML and all the CSS of my theme, also when I click with the right mouse button.

Comment: Not really a drupal issue. You can't stop someone from using firebug, and even if you did stop them from using right click, they could get around it with firebug.

Comment: Not a drupal issue.  Only way is a flash only site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the browser needs to download the markup and stylesheet to do its job, and you shouldn't try this kind of thing, It doesn't work and is annoying to site visitors.

Please read the answers on this similar StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597224/how-to-hide-html-source